# Coldfusion 8: Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at 127.0.0.1:8500

Tags: coldfusion

I installed Coldfusion 8 trial version on my system (XP Professional sp3).
I created an Folder in the “C:/Coldfusion8/wwwroot” called “buildProject” containing an Index.cfm and some other .cfm files.

But I am unable to access the Neither my project files or CFIDE/Administrator

I tried the following URLS

```
    http://localhost:8500/wwwroot/buildProject/ 
    http://localhost:8500/CFIDE/administrator/index.cfm
    http:// 127.0.0.1:8500/wwwroot/buildProject/ 
    http:// 127.0.0.1:8500/CFIDE/administrator/index.cfm
    http://localhost /wwwroot/buildProject/index.cfm
    http://localhost /CFIDE/administrator/index.cfm
    http://localhost /wwwroot/buildProject/ 
    http://localhost /CFIDE/administrator/index.cfm
```

Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at 127.0.0.1:8500.

```
*   The site could be temporarily unavailable or too busy. Try again in a few
      moments.

*   If you are unable to load any pages, check your computer's network
      connection.

*   If your computer or network is protected by a firewall or proxy, make sure
      that Firefox is permitted to access the Web.
```

• I cleared the browsing “History” from both IE and FF.
• I have restarted the CF server in the Control Panel >Administrative Tools > Services
• Even restarted the IIS

Getting the same error.

Further I was trying to access IE/FF via CFbuilder But still  I am getting the error
“The connection was refused when attempting to contact [URL].”

Comment: I just Checked My inetpub is in D: drive though i had installed the CF8 in C: drive will that effect?

Comment: This is a question better suited to ServerFault.

Comment: Can you see your coldfusion files from IIS Manager?

Comment: IIS managerAdministrative Tools> Internet Information Systems > (local system) >FTP Sites/Web Sites>
“>FTP Sites” has Default FTP Site > MyCompany
“> Web sites” is empty

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you connected Coldfusion to IIS, then you probably need to connect on port 80.  Which you did try, but if you connected Coldfusion to IIS, then the document root is IIS's document root, not the document root you created your new directory in.

I believe the document root for IIS on XP is c:\inetpub\wwwroot.

So, try putting a test.cfm file in there that just contains "hello world" or something, and see if you can request it from there.

Comment: My "inetpub" is in D: drive though i had installed the CF8 in C: drive! do i need to change it?

Comment: @Francis:  Probably not.  If you installed CF into IIS (instead of standalone), CF and IIS should be connected regardless of where the files actually lie.  I've routinely installed CF on C and run my websites from D.

Comment: No, you shouldn't need to change it.  Can you find where the CFIDE directory was put, though?

Comment: Ok.And CFIDE is in my D:\Inetpub\c0kpkv0\CFIDE

Comment: If you installed CF as standalone with its built in web server, this will have nothing at all to do with the IIS on the box and the default url will be "http://locahost:8500/" Whats the path to your coldfusion8/wwwroot folder and is there something in it?

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully you installed IIS first and were happy it was working before installing CF.

Try connecting to your IIS on http://localhost

You should get the default IIS .htm landing page , probably index.html or something, so at least you know IIS is working fine.

If you then try http://localhost/nosuchpage.htm you will see a 403 error (as long as you didnt specify to allow directory browsing). In the standard IIS error page you should be able to see

Physical Path   D:\inetpub\wwwroot

or wherever IIS thinks your web root is. When you then install CF to use IIS (rather than standalone) it will use this path as your web root.

Rename your index.html file as index.cfm and connect to it on

http://localhost:8500/index.cfm

If vanilla html pages are working from the directory but .cfm pages are not then you probably need an CFIDE mapping (I think one quick workaround is simply to copy your CFIDE folder and drop it into web root).

Comment: am unable to connect to http://localhost and "http://locahost/nosuchpage.htm " is leading to an external website

Comment: Edited my typo, meant it to say localhost with an "l"

Comment: Can you connect to any html web page running on this server ? If so whats the URL and the local path and what if any port are you specifying?

Comment: NO i am unable to connect even to an HTM file

Comment: If its a 404 file not found error, is there actually a test.htm page in your "D:\coldfusion8\wwwroot\" folder?

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you try typing this in as a url:
http://{your i.p. address}:8500/CFIDE/administrator/index.cfm

I bet it works